# twitter scraping. how to cumulative re-execution on the current result

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, controller, web-crawler

I'm scraping Twitter now. (Python)

It is a crawl that extracts tweets in real time with famous keywords.

If you do not have a tweet with keywords, it will be terminated.
(It has been successful so far.)

I wanted to create code that automatically executes after I enter the code, not when I quit by hand.
(Cumulative re-execution on the current result)

My first thought was to create a repeatable crawl code every 12 hours. 
But I can not run it ... I thought I had to set the code that I created to end when it was 12 hours.
(Repeat every 12 hours -> 12 hours to pause and run again)

I also think that it is not cumulative, but only tweets that are duplicated from the beginning.

I am writing this article to get advice on my code or advice on my thoughts

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

API_key = "x"
API_secret = "x"
Access_token = "x"
Access_token_secret = "x"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_term = 'x'
search_term2= 'x'
search_term3='x'
search_term4='x'
search_term5='x'

lat = "x"
lon = "x"
radius = "x"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)


c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3, search_term4, search_term5),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)


data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.35)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/wtt2.txt", mode='w')
data = {}
i = 0

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')
    i += 1

wfile.close()


from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', hours=12)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every 12 hours.')

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```